# iOS Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

So, I've been receiving many crash report from crashlytics for the past few days.So I check on crashltytics panel and I got **Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException** crash on many users. The crash is caused by **if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error])** from my method below:

```
- (void) saveContext{
 NSError *error = nil;

 NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

 if (managedObjectContext != nil)
 {
     if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error])
     {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
     }
 }
}
```

I read about quick fix regarding this issue is to delete the previous version of the app and then install the latest version. Do User have to do this every time there is a new version from my app?

How do I safely save context on iOS?